Angular - Esbuild chunk sizes do not match build output when served
I recently switched my Angular app to v18 and moved from webpack to esbuild. However, when comparing my chunk sizes with code splitting, I see the sizes do not make sense.
When using webpack, my production build gives 
And then when loaded in the browser, the downloaded sizes are at least similar
For example, main has raw size of 1.42MB and in browser it shows 1.5MB. Similarly, my lazy loaded profile feature shows 5.81kB raw and in browser loads as 6.4kB. While not identical, they are at least similarly sized.
Now when using esbuild without any changes or customization, I see these chunk sizes for production build
And then in the browser, my actual loaded sizes are much larger
Build shows main having raw size of 309.90kB and profile feature of 6.40kB but now the downloaded sizes are significantly higher at 1.7MB and 39.2kB respectively. And this goes for every chunk, not just these two.
This is when served locally in a production build. I understand that the estimated transfer size is when everything is gzipped and served in my actually deployment environment. But why are the sizes so much larger locally when building and serving with esbuild vs webpack?
Is this normal, or is there something im not understanding?

"This is when served locally in a production build" How exactly are you doing that? What happens when running a production build and serving the contents in the dist folder with a simple server, i.e. npx http-server? For ng serve, this issue was already reported in the Angular CLI GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27645

@JSONDerulo I am executing ng serve with the production build target so that it performs all the code optimizations, and serving it locally with the angular:dev-server. Is that not serving the contents in the dist folder already?

By using ng serve, the displayed chunk sizes are not reflecting the actual file sizes of the development server, regardless of the configuration used. This issue has already been reported in the Angular CLI GitHub repository: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27645. There the Angular team replied:

Development servers can perform transformation of code at runtime (typically on request) to support development workflows such as HMR, dependency prebundling, debugging, etc. The downloaded size will not necessarily match the initial built size nor is it intended to do so within the development server. While it is possible to use a production configuration with the development server, the result will still be a development-oriented browser experience.

When running ng build with the production configuration and opening a simple server which hosts the files, the chunk sizes should be accurate.

I see. As i mentioned, I have only just recently moved to esbuild, and I am only building, testing and working out bugs locally so far. I have no taken this to a dev or prd instance yet. I was doing comparisons between webpack and esbuild so I can understand the differences and benefits and explain them to my team. Based on this information, is it safe to assume that once deployed to our environments the sizes would more closely match the estimated transfer sizes?

Exactly, the chunk sizes should be accurate for production. This is just happening because the development server does a lot more than just hosting the files, to improve the developer experience. It's Interesting though that there is such a big difference compared to webpack, I don't really have an explanation for it.
